# replace one tag with another having class attribute using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to replace one html tag with another using asp.net.

```
 string html = rateNode.InnerHtml;
        string newHtml =html.Replace("<dl>", "<tr>").Replace("</dl>", "</tr>");
```

but it only replace the second part that is

```
.Replace("</dl>", "</tr>");
```

it does not replace the first part. the first part  is have class attribute. So i have also tried

```
 string html = rateNode.InnerHtml;
        string newHtml =html.Replace("<dl class='ui-attr-list util-clearfix'>", "<tr>").Replace("</dl>", "</tr>");
```

but failed. Please tell me what should i do for replacing the first part.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to replace the string "<dl>" which does not exists in your html variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the opening part of the tag.

```
.Replace("<dl", "<tr")
```

Comment: Would it make more sense to use regex replace to make sure it's exactly `dl`, so that something like (completely made up example) `<dll>` wasn't replaced with `<trl>`?  (Edit: just to be clear, I'm definitely NOT saying that you should use [regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/930393) but simply check this one instance)

Comment: Thanks @Keith Rousseau